# Why does the size of the binary executable increase by different amounts for the same block of code?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, executable

Let's say I have a C++ program and I compile it using g++. I then get an executable file which, as an example, has a size of 100 kb. I then add a couple of lines of C++ code and compile again and the size of the executable has increased to 101 kb. Then I add the **exact same** block of C++ code and compile a third time. This time the executable has increased to 106 kb. Why does it happen that the same code sometimes increases the size of the executable by one amount, and another time something much greater?

Also the big increase only happens every couple of times, most of the time it increases by the same, *small*, amount.

Comment: lines of code are not that useful as measure for code. C++ does not care about line breaks. You can write the exact same code in a single line or in 1k lines. To know why the executable size increases you should show the code

Comment: Pick any one (or more) of the following explanations: compiler heuristics matching a threshold, compiler heuristics **not** matching a threshold, elimination of redundant code, loop unrolling, sharing of code between lines, register spilling due to pressure

Comment: also consider `if (condition) { /* 100k lines of code */}` having either some impact on size of executable or none at all when the compiler can proove that `condition` is never `true`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number While of course you are right, even adding the (almost) same code multiple times will not necessarily increase the size linearly. This question should be improved to be more generic.

Comment: Come on, don't close this "lacks clarity". It's very clear. It might not be a great question, but "What affects compiled code size" is somewhat valid.

Comment: Put simply - the process of converting _lines of C++ code_ to _bytes of an executable_ is not linear and rather complex.

Comment: @PMF I didnt claim that executable sizes linear with size of code. I only said that lines of code is almost irrelevant. That doesnt imply that size of code is the better measure. ...should be improved to be *less* generic ?

Comment: @JesperElgh Are you fine with updating the question so it uses more distinct terminology?

Comment: Alright, I also see i formulated the question wrong. When I said the same number of lines were added, I meant the exact same piece of code. So the same block of code twice basically. If that makes any difference

Comment: @JesperElgh Yes, that's quite a big difference. You might want to update your question accordingly (use the "edit" button below your question)

Comment: @JesperElgh with that difference, the comment from Botje begins to scratch the surface.

Comment: @PMF Now I have updated the question :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I meant _more_ generic in the sense of not restricted to the fuzzy term "lines of code". But if we're talking about identical pieces being added, then I'm fine with that as well, of course.

Comment: Ask the linker to output a map file for each test and examine them to find where the differences lie.  Then ask the compiler to output the assembly code and compare the 2 sections identified in step (1)

Comment: It would greatly improve the question to show the actual code

Comment: If the program was built with any debug information, possibly the linker puts in some sort of extra information to aid in debugging, like time stamps, or some sort of check to make sure the object code matches the executable you're debugging, etc.  I know you tagged this with `gcc`, but for compilers like Visual C++, crash dumps can be debugged, but it has to be matched to the executable that crashed.  So there are some "cookies", whatever they may be, placed in the executable that matches the dump file.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of reasons why the size change of the resulting binary is not linear with the code size change. This is particularly true if some kind of optimization is enabled.

Even in debug mode (no optimizations), the following things could cause this to happen:

- The code size in the binary typically needs to be aligned to a certain size (dependent on the hardware). The size can only grow in multiplies of the alignment.
- The same applies for metadata tables (relocation tables, debug information)
- The compiler reserving extra space for debug information, based just on the number of methods/variables in use
- With some compilers (not sure about gcc), code in a binary can be updated in-place when only minor changes where done, instead of performing a full link on each build. This would result in different binary sizes when adding code and building vs. deleting the binary before each build.

If optimizations are enabled, it gets even more confusing, due to possible optimization strategies:

- The compiler may remove code he finds is unreachable
- If optimizing for speed, loop unrolling is a good thing to do, but only up to a certain degree. If adding more code inside the loop, the compiler might decide that the extra code size is no longer worth the speed gain.
- Also other optimizations work only up to a certain level, after which they do more harm than good. This could even result in the binary file getting *smaller* by adding code.

These are just a bunch of possible reasons, there might be many more.